# Problemas con Post en React: Código de Error 401

Tags: reactjs

Buenas les comento que estoy haciendo un projecto en React y tengo que crear un componente el cual permita al usuario enviar un comentario a través del metodo POST de la url(http://balearcs.patrykpy.com/balearcs/public/api/valoracions). He estado intentando otras maneras pero tampoco me solucionan nada. Estaria muy agradecido si alguien me pudiera resolver la duda

El error que me proporciona al enviar es:
[image: Erro consola]

La info del post seria algo tipo:

{   "comentari": "Bona visita",   "puntuacio": 5,   "fk_id_espai": 1,  "fk_id_usuari": 1 }

El codigo actual és:

```
import { Container, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import SelectEspais from './SelectEspais'; 

function Comentaris({ id : idUsuari }) {
    const [comentari, setComentari] = useState('');
    const [puntuacio, setPuntuacio] = useState(0);
    const [idEspai, setIdEspai] = useState('');
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { id, value } = e.target;
        if (id === 'comentari') setComentari(value);
        if (id === 'puntuacio') setPuntuacio(Number(value));
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        
        setIsLoading(true);

        const token = `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))}`;
        const valoracionData = {
            comentari,
            puntuacio,
            fk_id_espai: idEspai,
            fk_id_usuari: idUsuari,
        };

        console.log('Información acumulada:', valoracionData);

        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                'http://balearcs.patrykpy.com/balearcs/public/api/valoracions',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        Authorization: token,
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(valoracionData),
                }
            );

            if (response.ok) {
                console.log('Comentario enviado correctamente');
                setComentari('');
                setPuntuacio(0);
                setIdEspai('');
                
            } else {
                console.error('Error al enviar el comentario');
                setError('Ha ocurrido un error al enviar la valoración.');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error de red:', error);
            setError('Ha ocurrido un error al enviar la valoración.');
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Container className="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div className="w-100">
                <h1 className="text-center mt-3 mb-3 p-4 border">
                    Deja tu comentario y valoración
                </h1>
                <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                    <Form className="w-75" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="comentari">
                            <Form.Label>Comentario</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Escribe tu comentario"
                                value={comentari}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="puntuacio">
                            <Form.Label>Puntuación (1-5)</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                as="select"
                                value={puntuacio}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            >
                                <option value="0">Selecciona una puntuación</option>
                                <option value="1">★</option>
                                <option value="2">★★</option>
                                <option value="3">★★★</option>
                                <option value="4">★★★★</option>
                                <option value="5">★★★★★</option>
                            </Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>
                        {/* Renderiza el componente SelectEspais */}
                        <SelectEspais onSelectEspai={setIdEspai} />
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" disabled={isLoading}>
                            {isLoading ? 'Enviando...' : 'Enviar Comentario'}
                        </Button>
                        {error && <p className="text-danger mt-3">{error}</p>}
                    </Form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Comentaris;
```

Comment: Tienes un 401 en la consola, es un error de [autorización](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) , hay un problema con el token que estas tratando de pasar, verifica que `const token = Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))};` este trayendo la información correcta.

Comment: Nada al final cambiando la api puede conseguirlo. Muchas gracias igualmente